# Identify Duplicate Invoice number with prefix or suffixe

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I'm using access 2013 and trying to identify duplicate payments made to vendors. I use the SQL query below to identify different type of duplicates but it is not giving desired results as sometimes two criteria are different like invoice number and invoice date.

```
SELECT 
Base.ID AS SerialNumber, 
Base.CoCd AS CoCode, 
Base.DocumentNo AS DocID, 
Base.ClrngdocNo AS ClearingDoc, 
Base.DocumentType AS DocType, 
Base.Account AS VendorName, 
Base.Reference AS InvoiceNumber, 
Base.DocumentDate AS InvoiceDate, 
Base.GrossInvoiceAmount AS InvAmount

FROM RawData2017TillDate AS Base 
INNER JOIN RawData2017TillDate AS duplicate 
ON (Base.ID <> duplicate.ID) 
AND (Base.Account = duplicate.Account) 
AND (Base.Reference <> duplicate.Reference) 
AND (Base.DocumentDate = duplicate.DocumentDate) 
AND (Base.GrossInvoiceAmount = duplicate.GrossInvoiceAmount)
ORDER BY Base.GrossInvoiceAmount DESC , Base.reference DESC;
```

I just want single query to identify duplicate with one or more characters added at the begining or at the end of invoice number like examples below
2713565
2713565R, 
01456
1456,
I-0001118588
1118588

Also, if I could get a better query to identify duplicates based on other criteria will be appreciated. I am looking for a single query for all criteria.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please try like below:

I grouped invoice numbers based on their first 2 letters.

```
SELECT  
Mid(Base.reference, 1, 2) , count(1)
FROM RawData2017TillDate AS Base 
INNER JOIN RawData2017TillDate AS duplicate 
ON (Base.ID <> duplicate.ID) 
AND (Base.Account = duplicate.Account) 
AND (Base.Reference <> duplicate.Reference) 
AND (Base.DocumentDate = duplicate.DocumentDate) 
AND (Base.GrossInvoiceAmount = duplicate.GrossInvoiceAmount)
group by  Mid(Base.reference, 1, 2) ;
```